# How to reset mailuser password for EXO?

Tags: office-365, user-accounts, exchange-online

As administrator for my Office365 domain, I have to reset the password for mailuser accounts (Exchange Online), and I want to do this via powershell.

These are the accounts that I issue so folks can have access to my Sharepoint Portal.  So this is about sharepoint accounts.

The best I can come up with so far is this:

```
set-mailbox -identity $username -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
The operation couldn't be performed because object 'xxxxx@somewhere.com' couldn't be found on blablabla.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM'.

+CategorInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [Set-Mailbox], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
```

How can I do it?

[a week later]

Does anyone have a clue?  How can I use powershell to reset the password for a Mail-User account?  I've tried everything and have googled the world over.  So, there is [`set-msoluser`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/msonline/v1/set-msoluser) but no parameter within for setting the actual password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, finally.

You have to treat Mail-User Accounts like full Office365 Accounts.  AND you have to specify the UPN with the internal email address that you assigned the Mail-User account when you created it - complete with the domain designation.  You can't do it with just the username itself.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/msonline/v1/set-msoluserpassword

Actually, here is how to do it in powershell:

```
get-recipient -identity b.newhart | select windowsLiveID
#returns b.newhart@mydomain.com
```

This will fetch the internal email address which is the UserID that can be used in the `Set-MsolUserPassword` command.